# How to set a double for loop to scan an image from top left to bottom right?

Tags: python, image, loops

I would like to count all the pixel colors in a picture from top left to bottom right, going line by line. I need to count  only 1 pixel color every 5 pixel on the lines, and count only 1 row out of 5.

```
count = 0
for y in range(height,height +5):
    for x in range(width,width+5):
         ''' some code here counting pixel colors '''
return count 
''' some other function that does height+=1, width +=1'''
```

Could you help as my piece of code is not working and scanning properly?

Comment: No, it wouldn't - this should work as it moves row-wise. Or actually I don't quite understand what you think the problem is.

Comment: you should fix your ranges and it should work, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoudld change your code like this, so to start the for loops at 0, up to picture size, then increase by +5 steps:

```
count = 0
for y in range(0,height, +5):
    for x in range(0, width,+5):
         ''' some code here counting pixel colors '''
return count
''' some other function that does height+=1, width +=1'''
```

This suppose top left corner is the (0,0) screen pixel